# не работает Gulp watch sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Сервер запускается и watcher отрабатывает только на файлы с расширением .html, на изменения в .scss и в .js никак не реагирует, не работает наблюдатель

======================================

пути к файлам

======================================

```
const pathSrc = "./src";
const pathDest = "./build";

module.exports = {
    root: pathDest,

    html: {
        src: pathSrc + "/html/*.html",
        watch: pathSrc + "/html/**/*.html",
        dest: pathDest
    },
    scss: {
        src: pathSrc + "/styles/*.{sass,scss}",
        watch: pathSrc + "/styles/**/*.{sass, scss}",
        dest: pathDest + "/styles"
    },
    js: {
        src: pathSrc + "/js/*.js",
        watch: pathSrc + "/js/**/*.js",
        dest: pathDest + "/js"
    },
    img: {
        src: pathSrc + "/assets/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}",
        watch: pathSrc + "/assets/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}",
        dest: pathDest + "/assets"
    },
    font: {
        src: pathSrc + "/font/*.{eot,ttf,otf,ttc,woff,woff2,svg}",
        watch: pathSrc + "/font/**/*.{eot,ttf,otf,ttc,woff,woff2,svg}",
        dest: pathDest + "/font"
    }
}
```

=======================================

gulpfile.js

=======================================

```
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


//--====================CONFIG====================--//


const path = require("./config/path")


//--====================TASKS=====================--//


const html = require('./task/html');

const scss = require('./task/scss');

const js = require('./task/js');

const img = require('./task/img');

const font = require('./task/font');

//==============================SERVER

const server = () => {

    browserSync.init({

        server: {

            baseDir: path.root,

    }

    });

}

//==============================WATCHER

const watcher = () => {

     gulp.watch(path.scss.watch, scss).on("all", browserSync.reload);

     gulp.watch(path.html.watch, html).on("all", browserSync.reload);

     gulp.watch(path.js.watch, js).on("all", browserSync.reload);

     gulp.watch(path.img.watch, img).on("all", browserSync.reload);

     gulp.watch(path.font.watch, font).on("all", browserSync.reload);
 }

//=============================EXPORTS

//exports.watch = watcher;

exports.html = html;

exports.scss = scss;

exports.js = js;

exports.img = img;

exports.font = font;



exports.dev = gulp.series(

    gulp.parallel(html, scss, js, img, font),

    gulp.parallel(watcher, server)

);
```

Comment: предположу, что конвертация в css не идет (если это полный код сборщика). а вобще примеров gulpfile.js в [интернете](https://www.google.com/search?q=gulp+file+sample+site%253Agithub.com) просто куча (я в свое время тоже [писал](https://github.com/miptleha/FrontendTemplate/blob/master/gulpfile.js)). они все плюс-минус похожи. возьмите себе за основу первый работающий и используйте.

Comment: ```const scss = () => {
    return gulp.src(path.scss.src)
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler:notify.onError()
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sassImport())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.scss.dest))
}

module.exports = scss;```

Comment: вроде нормально. трудно сказать в чем дело... нужно все исходники смотреть, может в package.json не все модули. может scss-файл не в той папке, может релиз смотрите вместо дебаг-версии. 100 разных причин может быть. вы же не сами весь этот сборщик написали? взяли за основу чужой? он работал? если не работал, то просто возьмите другой. их тысячи (я свой по [ютюбу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7yYD3qVchw) писал).